# Doctrine Query Builder: Value in SQL array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have an array of entities (groups) in an entity (user), and in my Query Builder I would like to do something like this:

```
$groups = $current_user->getGroups();
$usersQuery = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')->createQueryBuilder('u');

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $usersQuery
        ->orWhere(':group_value in (u.groups)')
        ->setParameter('group_value', $group);
}
```

But doctrine doesn't like it.
Is there another way to check if a value is in a SQL array ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MEMBER OF` DQL statement for these cases:

```
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $usersQuery
        ->orWhere(':group_value MEMBER OF u.groups')
        ->setParameter('group_value', $group);
}
```

Definition: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#collection-expressions